# iOS: how to open multiple links in new tabs on Safari?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, safari

The goal is to open different tabs in mobile Safari with different links.

However, this code only opens one URL -- the first one. The others never get opened.

Presumably, this default behavior guards against some app opening 100 tabs, or some crazy number of tabs, at once.

It is possible in JavaScript on a web page to open multiple tabs with different URLs.

Is this possible on iOS with Swift?

```
let urls = ["http://www.google.com", "http://www.espn.com", "http://www.fox.com"]

for u in urls {
    if let url = URL(string: u) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
    }
}
```